# Share image via other apps in android

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, uri

I am successfully retrieving the Image and displaying it in a list but while i am sharing it, it's showing that "Empty file can not be attched"

here are what I've tried

```
  holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/"+ listItem.getImg();
            File f = new File(PATH);
            Uri yourUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
         //   Uri contenturi= FileProvider.getUriForFile(context," com.astu360.bjp2017",f);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("Image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, yourUri);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"These are the content..");
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Share via.."));
        }
    });
```

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to embed the image as a base64 string into the extra? I will have to do the same with a Keystore next week.

Comment: @Xvolks How to do that ...?? can you share that part of code ..i'll be thankful to u

Answer (score 0):

you should use bitmap to compress and try chooser.

```
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/*");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 150, bytes);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "file.jpg");
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share..."));
```

Comment: what if I have multiple types of images

Comment: http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/ this will helpyou.